# `netstat` doesn't show sockets binded by python SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp, netstat

A local server is run using the **SimpleHTTPServer** module from Python 2.7

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Then I use netstat to search for that socket using 8000 as a filter for port number, however, I can't find any socket with the filter (even when I open a browser window and access `127.0.0.1:8000`).

```
$ netstat | grep 8000
// "return Nothing"
```

Does anyone have ideas about why I can't see the socket binded by Python SimpleHTTPServer in `netstat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that `0.0.0.0` means that your server will be listing on all IP addresses of your machine, so change the IP address on your python code from `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, if you want to run it locally.

And better run : `netstat -an|grep 8000`

Comment: If I use `127.0.0.1`, it seems the server can only be accessed by a local machine. I'm just wondering why using `0.0.0.0:8000` can't be monitored by `netstat`..

Comment: try to run `netstat -an|grep 8000` instead?

Comment: No pblm @hanfeisun, feel free to accept my answer if you are happy with it

Answer (score 5):

Extending the answer by @MK.

---

By default, `netstat` shows only the **connected ports**, but **NOT** those which just listening idly. Hence, the confusion.
The author of `netstat` made the call either for simplicity or for aesthetics.

if you make a connection to that `:8000` port, it will show up in just `netstat` call.

Else, you have to make it explicit that you want it **ALL**.

```
netstat -a | grep 8000
```

Comment: hah, good point.  I never even understood the imporatnce of that -a, so used to typing it...

Answer (score 1):

When you run netstat w/o the `-n` argument it will display addresses as names, including protocols.  So if you were listening on port 80 it would show up as, say, `localhost:http` and your grep for 8000 would not find it.  In your case it is port 8000 and according to

```
grep 8000 /etc/services
```

it probably shows up as localhost:irdmi

Running

```
netstat -na
```

will get around that and report the more useful :8000.
It is funny how default mode of netstat is both more "friendly" and is almost always less useful than -n.

Comment: imo, this should the "Accepted" answer.
btw, who wondering `-n` stands for `--numeric : don't resolve names` and `-a` for `--all:  display all sockets (default: connected)`